# Generate event on click of outer div in backbone.js

Tags: html, backbone.js

How to generate click event on only outer div but not on click of its children

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(''),
    events: {
        'click #main-content li': 'AccordionChangingIcons', //For user li click event
    },
});
```

This is HTML code.

```
<li class="icon-left" id="1"><i class="icon-glass"></i><span class="om-drag"></span><span class="om-delete"></span><h3 contenteditable="true" class="item">title1-goes-here</h3><div contenteditable="true" style="max-height: 100px; display: block;" class="content">   Content goes here1 check here</div></li>
```

Comment: Where is that HTML in relation to the view? Does it end up inside the view's `el`?

Comment: Please assume that html code is inside template and li is within div having id main-content. If i click on <i> tag event is getting generated.I want event to generate only after clicking li but not its children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone uses event delegation to attach event listeners which is in some situations a bit more complicated to work with than whith events bound directly.

Event delegation in both jQuery and Zepto (you didn't specify if you use either one in your Backbone app, but I assume you do) works like this:

```
$( some_element ).on( event, selector, function(){} )
```

In Backbone `some_element` is views `el` element reference, event and selector are, in your example, `click` and `#main-content li`. So the `click` event listener is attached to view's `el`, and when you click anywhere within your view the event is fired, then jQuery/Zepto checks if the element clicked matches selector passed. This of course makes it impossible to listen to events on elements outside view's `el` element.

Now to the point: events passed to callback functions in these libraries are normalized, but include a reference to the original (browser's native) event object. You can use both to check what was really clicked on and if you want to take action.

In your example you only want to proceed if `event.currentTarget === event.originalEvent.target`. `currentTarget` is in the libraries' normalized event object and always refers to your `li`. `originalEvent.target` is the browser's native event target and refers to the element which was actually clicked on, which will refer to the deepest nested node in the tree beginning at `li`. So if both point to `li`, then the user has clicked on it, a not any of its children.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAbpD/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be solved like this:
[How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Either by creating a separate view for the outer area or by attaching an outer-event via jquery:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(''),
    events: {
        'click #main-content li': 'AccordionChangingIcons', //For user li click event
    },
    initialize: function() {
        $("html").on("click", this.outsideClick);
    },
    outsideClick: function() {
        //handle outside click
    },
    AccordionChangingIcons: function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: But be careful with that solution: it may break some behaviour for other outside clicks.